# How to calculate the contrast of an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Let's say I have an `opencv` `BGR` image `img`, how to calculate the contrast of that image?

Comment: For anyone in the future, I suggest starting with the following paper (No Reference Color Image Contrast and Quality Measures), which lists both grayscale-based and color-based contrast measures: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=6626251

Answer (score 18, accepted):

One definition of contrast is [RMS Contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(vision)#RMS_contrast), it can be calculated as follows:

First, transform the `BGR` image `img` to greyscale:

```
img_grey = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
```

Lastly, calculate the standard deviation of the greyed image pixel intensities:

```
contrast = img_grey.std()
```

Comment: RMS contrast is not the only contrast definition. I find Weber and Michelson far more common.

Comment: @Piglet feel free to post the answer you consider more relevant, just updated my answer clarifying I'm providing a solution for RMS Contrast calculation.

Comment: Any documentation for this std() function?

Comment: @NadavB std() is the standard deviation of the values in the array

Comment: I'd like to add that there are quite many contrast measures. The choice will probably depend on the use case and the image content.

Answer (score 8):

Here is one measure of contrast: [Michelson contrast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contrast_(vision)#Michelson_contrast) and how to compute it in Python/OpenCV/Numpy. Low contrast is near zero and high contrast is near one. Use the Y (intensity) channel from YUV or YCbCr or alternately the L channel from LAB or even just convert the image to grayscale and use that.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image as YUV (or YCbCR) and select Y (intensity)
# or convert to grayscale, which should be the same.
# Alternately, use L (luminance) from LAB.
img = cv2.imread("barn.jpg")
Y = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2YUV)[:,:,0]

# compute min and max of Y
min = np.min(Y)
max = np.max(Y)

# compute contrast
contrast = (max-min)/(max+min)
print(min,max,contrast)
```

Returns:

0 255 1.0

The contrast will be between 0 and 1.

Comment: Mark, I do not see `sat`. Where have I mistyped that.

Comment: Mark, thanks. Fixed! I looked at that 10 times and missed it. Copy and edit from another post I made and overlooked that. Sorry, all.

Comment: I wonder how is this usually applied in reality?  Always after de-noise? Segmenting then averaging the entire picture's contrasts?