# How to measure the saturation of an image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Consider the input as an `opencv` `BGR` image `img`, how to measure the saturation of that image?

Comment: Regarding [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58821130/11089932) and this one here: Are you planning to drop [canonical Q&As](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291992/11089932)? Have you tried searching other Q&As, which might already have good answers, and maybe improve these?

Comment: Yes I searched and didn't find what I was looking for in SO, that is why I decided to do these after finding the answers somewhere else. If you find duplicates of these questions please point them to me.

Comment: Just my two cents regarding this question here: Google "saturation image", find https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorfulness#Saturation. Read about HSV color space there; S is saturation, nice. Google "opencv HSV", find https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/df/d9d/tutorial_py_colorspaces.html, and subsequent information there. Nice, there's color conversion from BGR to HSV, second channel is saturation. Done.

Comment: The idea of this post is to make the path from question to answer easier, that's all it is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To start, transform the `BGR` image `img` to `HSV`:

```
img_hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
```

Finally, calculate the mean of the 2nd channel the `HSV` image, which is nothing but the saturation channel:

```
saturation = img_hsv[:, :, 1].mean()
```