# Determine how colorblind-friendly an image is

Tags: python, color-blindness

I am wanting to create a function that would determine how colorblind-friendly an image is (on a scale from 0-1). I have several color-related functions that are capable of performing the following tasks:

- Take an image (as a PIL image, filename, or RGB array) and transform it into an image representative of what a colorblind person would see (for the different types of colorblindness)
- Take an image and determine the rgb colors associated with each pixel of the image (transform into numpy array of rgb colors)
- Determine the color palette associated with an image
- Find the similarity between two rgb arrays (using CIELAB- see colormath package)

My first instinct was to transform the image and colorblind version of the image into RGB arrays and then use the CIELAB function to determine the similarity between the two images. However, that doesn't really solve the problem since it wouldn't be able to pick out things like readability (e.g. if the text and background color end up being very similar after adjusting for colorblindness).

Any ideas for how to determine how colorblind-friendly an image is?

Comment: i'm colorblind and it's only when images contain strong colors. More than two colors can also be quite bad. There's 7 [types](https://www.nei.nih.gov/learn-about-eye-health/eye-conditions-and-diseases/color-blindness/types-color-blindness) i'd focus on working on a few types first, then catering to all if you know what I mean. Research the types then detect them colors to determine how colorblind-friendly an image is. [This](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/08/04/opencv-python-color-detection/) might help you.

Comment: For text specifically: you can run OCR on the image before and after transformation (using the pytesseract library e.g.). For general differences between pre-transformation and post-transformation images, you can look at contrast; see this question for instance: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58821130/how-to-calculate-the-contrast-of-an-image

Overall this is a really broad question and is probably too broad for a single stackoverflow question. Good luck on your project, sounds interesting!

Comment: @Insula Thanks for the resource. I'm mostly focusing on deuteronopia, protonapia,  and tritanopia, all of which I have functions to convert to.

Comment: @C_Z_ Thanks! I'll check it out. I'm aware it's a bit of a stretch for stack overflow questions, but just needed a starting point. Thanks again